# Multiple hour by a number

Tags: php

I have something like that for example: `01:06:22` this represents 1hour, 6minutes and 22seconds. I want to take that, and multiple it by 6 and add it to some other hour such as `04:23` which is 4AM and 23Minutes **not 4hours and 23 minutes**.

Basically, as a result I expect that:

`01:06:22` 
* 6 **=** 6hours 38minutes **canceling the remaining seconds which are 12 in this case**

Now, I want to take that and append it to other hour, `04:23` in this case, so the result would be:
`11:01`.

I have no clue how to start and do it, unfortunately.

Any help is appriciated!

### ***Clarifications***

The time that I have to multiple by 6 will ***never*** exceed 2 hours.

All the times are in the same format.

Comment: What if we have time like 06:12:30 than we need to multiple by 6? after multiplcation it is appro. 37:12:30  so it will be next day?

Comment: Do the timecode strings always have the same format?
In which case, you can detect which kind it is (either the first case, either the 2nd case) and do your calculations.

In general to manipulate timecode, the easiest thing is to convert everything to second and do your calculations.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi I forgot to mention, the hour that I have to multiple by 6 will NEVER exceed 2 hours

Comment: In any case, you should convert everything to second.
multiply or whatever, then put it back in the right format. That will save you some trouble

Comment: @dyesdyes I've edited my post. BTW, I have no idea how to even start what I'm looking for, so if you could "throw me a bone" it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) it is simple:

```
$time = '01:06:22';
$dateSeconds = new DateTime("1970-01-01 $time UTC");
$seconds = $dateSeconds->getTimestamp() * 6;
$interval = new DateInterval('PT'.$seconds.'S');
$date = new DateTime('1970-01-01 04:23:00 UTC');
$date->add($interval);
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
```

Other solution with [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [gmdate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php). (Similar to Suresh but working):

```
$date = strtotime('1970-01-01 01:06:22 UTC');
$add = strtotime('1970-01-01 04:23:00 UTC');
$date = (($date*6)+$add);
echo gmdate('H:i:s', $date);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution if you want to implement it yourself.

The thing about timecode is that it can become really heavy with the if the if conditions etc if you don't do it right.

The best Way I thought of to deal with this is to convert everything to second.

so 01:06:22 would become:

```
numberOfSecond = 22 + 06 * 60 + 01 * 60 * 60
```

How to get the 22, 06 etc from the String? You can use Regex.

What you will need:

- a function to extract the different values (hours, minute, second)
- a function to convert the timecode into second
- a function to convert back into timecode
- the functions to multiply, add etc...

You might want to create a class for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
$date = strtotime('01:06:22');
$add = strtotime('00:04:23');
$date = ($date*6)+$add;
echo date('H:i:s', $date);
```

Note: Code is not tested.

Comment: This code depends on the default timezone value; it won't work correctly if that is not UTC.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you want to multiply a time span by a factor. The easiest way to do this is to convert the span to seconds and do a straight multiply:

```
$date =DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i:s', '01:06:22', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$seconds = $date->getTimestamp();
```

This code works by pretending that the time is a moment during the Unix epoch start so that it can then get the number of seconds elapsed since the epoch (the timestamp). That number is equal to the duration of the time span in seconds. However, it is **vitally important** that the input is interpreted as UTC time and not as something in your local time zone.

An equivalent way of doing things (as long as the input is in the correct format) which is lower-tech but perhaps less prone to bugs would be

```
list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', '01:06:22');
$seconds = $h * 3600 + $m * 60 + $s;
```

Now the multiplication:

```
$seconds = $seconds * 6;
```

If you want to only keep whole minutes from the time you can do so at this stage:

```
$seconds = $seconds - $seconds % 60;
```

The final step of adding the result to a given "time" is not clearly specified yet -- does the reference time contain date information? What happens if adding to it goes over 24 hours?

Answer (score 1):

Self explanatory :

```
$initialTime = '01:06:22';

$timeToAdd = '04:23';

$initialTimeExploded = explode( ':' ,$initialTime );

$initialTimeInMintues = ( $initialTimeExploded[0] * 60 ) + $initialTimeExploded[1];

$initialTimeInMintuesMultipliedBySix = $initialTimeInMintues * 6;

$timeToAddExploded = explode( ':' ,$timeToAdd );

$timeToAddExplodedInMintues = ( $timeToAddExploded[0] * 60 ) + $timeToAddExploded[1];

$newTimeInMinutes = $initialTimeInMintuesMultipliedBySix + $timeToAddExplodedInMintues;

$newTime = floor( $newTimeInMinutes / 60 ) .':' .($newTimeInMinutes % 60);

echo $newTime;
```

Result :

```
10:59
```